# Can I change an item inside customArray

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio

hello I want to modify some data inside custom ArrayList

my Custom Array

```
public class Item_GetMembers {

    String userid,username,gender,admin,ban,type;

    public Item_GetMembers(String userid, String username, String gender, String admin, String ban, String type) {
        this.userid = userid;
        this.username = username;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.admin = admin;
        this.ban = ban;
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

I want to modify ban from 0 to 1 postion 3 Can I do it from the same page or not?

my Adapter

```
 public class Adapter_GetMembers extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter_GetMembers.AdapterHolder>{

        ArrayList<Item_GetMembers> CategoriesList;
        Context context;

        public Adapter_GetMembers(Context context , ArrayList<Item_GetMembers> categories) {
            this.context = context;
            CategoriesList = categories;
        }

        @Override
        public AdapterHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_getmembers,parent,false);
            AdapterHolder adapterHolder = new AdapterHolder(v);

            return adapterHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final AdapterHolder holder, final int position) {
            final Item_GetMembers item_getMembers = CategoriesList.get(position);
item_getMembers.ban.get(3,1); //but wrong why??

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return CategoriesList.size();
        }

        class AdapterHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {

            public AdapterHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

            }
        }
```

}

can I edit data within it? I tried a lot to modify it but it did not work
  , thanks in advance

Comment: you mean you want to move your model position from 0 to 1, right?

Comment: yes of course :D

Comment: I want change data postion 3 from 0 to 1

Comment: for example :
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        names.add("A");
        names.add("B");
        names.add("C");
        names.add("D");

I want change for example name A to Haley you understand me?

Comment: check my updated code

Comment: "item_getMembers.ban.get(3,1); //but wrong why??" - well, *ban* is a `String`. There is no get(int, int ) method for `String`. Maybe you wanted to say `CategoriesList.get(3).ban = String.valueOf(1);` ?

Comment: I know but this comment :D

, I have users and ban if 1 then he banned 0 else , I want change data from arraylist from 0 to 1 or else

Comment: I seen your updated but where write 0 or 1?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final AdapterHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Item_GetMembers item_getMembers = CategoriesList.get(position);
    //It means if your position is zero then zero position item will move at third position
    if(position == 0)
       moveItem(3, item_getMembers);

}

private void moveItem(int toItemPos, Item_GetMembers item)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < CategoriesList.size(); i++){
        if(toItemPos == i){
            CategoriesList.add(i, item)
            break;              
        }
   }
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: no man for example I have 2 name in array

postion 0 name = "A"
postion 1 name = "B"

I want change postion 0 from A to Haley

Comment: you understand me?

Comment: but where write new name??